# Find rows within multiple arrays that have the same header and remove all other rows, using Matlab

Tags: matlab

In Matlab, I have several txt files that I have loaded and converted to matrices.  The matrices represent temperature data at different cities around the world.  The first column in each matrix is a year.  Each file spans a different range of years but they all overlap for a few of those years.  I would like to find where the overlap, and either extract out (or delete non-overlapping years) so that when I plot the data, each data set is using the same span of years.  The code should be able to ingest an unknown number of these txt files.  I have tried to use the "intersect" function but that will work on an element-by-element basis.  I want all data for overlapping years, so the elements (except for the header) will be different.

An example of current code:

```
clear all 
files = dir('.txt'); 
num_files = length(files); 
mintersect(files); 
for i=1:num_files 
    eval(['load ' files(i).name ' -ascii']); 
    vals{i} = load(files(i).name); 
    matrix = vals{i}; 
    station = (files(i).name(1:end-4)); 
    matrix(matrix == 999.9) = NaN; 
    matrix(matrix == -99.0) = NaN; 
    years = matrix(:,1); 
    months = matrix(:,2:13)'; 
    figure, hold on 
    plot(years, months,''); 
    ylabel('Temp.'); 
    xlabel('Years'); 
    grid on; 
    title(sprintf('Mean Monthly Temperature for %s Station',station)); 
end
```

Comment: A (small) example would really help here.

Comment: clear all

files = dir('*.txt');
num_files = length(files);

mintersect(files);

for i=1:num_files
    eval(['load ' files(i).name ' -ascii']);
    vals{i} = load(files(i).name);
    matrix = vals{i};
    station = (files(i).name(1:end-4));
    matrix(matrix == 999.9) = NaN;
    matrix(matrix == -99.0) = NaN;
    years = matrix(:,1);
    months = matrix(:,2:13)';
    figure, hold on
    plot(years, months,'*');
    ylabel('Temp.');
    xlabel('Years');
    grid on;
    
    title(sprintf('Mean Monthly Temperature for %s Station',station));
end

Comment: Sorry I'm new to Stackoverflow and I didn't mean for my code to be all jumbled up like that.

Comment: @user1813430 I have added your code to the question. you can do this by editing the question, you do not need to put the code in comments.